# wireless for MiniPC

Tags: installation, wireless

I bought a Giada i35V with no software and tried to install Ubuntu 12LTS which runs through install but I cannot make Wifi work, the driver doesn't have .inf file so the windows driver program doesn't work.

I tried install of Ubuntu 12.10, the wireless adapter works in initial screen but it won't boot from USB and the install will finish but when I try to boot up again the process stalls at 'checking battery status' and freezes so I can't get in.

Does anyone know how I could install LTS and find the linux driver for the wifi or fix 12.10 install?

Answer (score 0):

**12.10 refusing to boot**
Problems with booting can be attributed to ACPI issues; you can try to boot without it.

Hold <kbd>R Shift</kbd> when the computer is booting, you should be presented with a menu.
Hit <kbd>e</kbd> with the Ubuntu 12.10 selected, use the arrow keys to move the cursor down to the end of the line starting with "linux" (this line may span several lines, you can spot this by trying to move up or down).

Type `acpi=off`, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.
If it boots (and provides wifi), edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `acpi=off` at the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, but still within the quotes.

Finish up by executing `sudo update-grub`.

**12.04 Wifi issue**
If you're lucky, the archive manager can extract the needed file from your executable.
Should that fail, you can try the [Universal Extractor](http://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract#download), which supposedly is [very compatible with Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6121).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem not detect wireless and graphic in Giada i35u. I installed 12.04 LTS on that device. And I change the kernel version to 3.2.0-44-generic. After upgrading graphic and wireless driver detected. You can download and update from this site:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/proposed/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-3.2.0-44-generic

May Enjoy!